# sessions_start returns true despite of internal error

Tags: php

Following code:

```
    $s = @session_start();
    logMessage($this->debugLevel, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" . print_r($s, true));
    if ( $s === false )
    {
        // session not established!
        throw new \Exception("Session could not be started");
    }
```

I have configured memcached as session store. Memcache is not running and this generates a notice:

```
   PHP Notice:  session_start(): Server xxx (tcp 11211) failed with ...
```

so far as expected, **BUT**, `$s` is **always** `true`, even if the session obviously can not be started at all.

Q1: what's wrong with this?
Q2: how can I catch the error ... ?

**EDIT:**

This:

```
    if ( session_start() === false )
    {
        // session not established!
        throw new \Exception("Session could not be started");
    }
```

doesn't change anything. Same as above. Exception NOT thrown.

**EDIT 2:**

memcache (1)

```
        $mc = new MemcachedConf();
        session_save_path('' . $mc );
        session_module_name("memcache");
```

memcache (2)

it's a 300 loc class, main part:

```
        if ( $this->memcache == null )
        $this->memcache = new Memcache();
        return $this->memcache;
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- it should be, `@` is php error suppression symbol.

Comment: Yes. http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Before the call to session_start() put in a call to session_save_path() and give it the name of a directory writable by the serve

Comment: @PHPMan read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: @deceze thanks. Memcache is working fine, it's just to have a proper error handling and that's why I tested w/o a running memcache.

Comment: which version of PHP are you running? before PHP 5.3 session_start() was returning TRUE even on fail.... (see changelog http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: @saty as of memcache there shouldn't be any "path". It's the nature of memcache to NOT store ANYTHING in files.